# Binding ToggleButton IsChecked property to another ToggleButton not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have two `ToggleButtons`.

I need to bind one `IsChecked` property to the other `ToggleButton`.

I use a custom `Converter` to inverse the value.

However, it's not working? Here's my code:

XAML:

```
<ToggleButton 
    IsChecked="{Binding Path=ToggleButton.IsChecked, ElementName=menuCatUit, 
    Converter={StaticResource InvertBool}}"/>

<ToggleButton x:Name="menuCatUit" IsChecked="True" />
```

Code:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(bool))]
public class InverseBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(bool))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");

        return !(bool)value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use two RadioButtons if you want only one of them to be checked at a time

Comment: @FlatEric Not an option for GUI reasons.

Comment: Do you mean the look of the elements? You could simply override the control template and make it look how you want

Comment: I know, but why would make a `RadioButton`any difference? I just need the binding to work :D

Comment: Because RadioButton provides the functionality you require and you normally choose the Control by functionality and change the appearance if required and not the other way round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

I needed to edit my `converter` because `ToggleButton` uses a `nullable bool`.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool?), typeof(bool))]
public class InverseNullableBool : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(bool?))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a nullable boolean");

        bool? b = (bool?)value;
        return !(b.HasValue && b.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "ToggleButton" from the path property.
You only need  the property name.

```
<ToggleButton 
    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=menuCatUit, 
    Converter={StaticResource InvertBool}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i Do, I send them all to the same Checked and UnChecked event:

```
privateToggleButton Toggle;
public void ToggleButtonChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Toggle != null && Toggle != sender as ToggleButton)
        {
            Toggle.IsChecked = false;
        }

        Toggle = sender as ToggleButton;
    }

    public void ToggleButtonUnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Toggle != null)
        {
            Toggle = null;
        }
    }
```

And then to check which ToggleButton is checked do something like this

```
switch (Toggle.Name)
                {
                    case ("Button1"): /*MyCode*/ break;
                };
```